# MySQL combining 2 separate queries into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to produce a report where I track inbound and outbound shipments from a location, with the result being the tally of how many of each SKU came in and went out.

An “inbound” SKU has it’s *dest_loc* set to “LOC1”, while an “outbound” one has it's *source_loc* set to “LOC1”, LOC1 being the location of reference.

There is a special destination value called “REC”, meaning Recycled.

Each SKU has source_loc and dest_loc values (no null cases). This example has three SKUs, and 5 possible locations.

```
sku source_loc  dest_loc
sku1    LOC2    LOC1
sku1    LOC1    LOC1   <-- src=dest is a valid case
sku2    LOC3    LOC1
sku3    LOC4    LOC1
sku3    LOC4    LOC1
sku3    LOC1    LOC4
sku3    LOC1    LOC3
sku1    LOC1    LOC2
sku2    LOC3    LOC1
sku2    LOC1    REC
```

The final report would look like this:

```
sku     inbound     outbound    recycle
sku1    2           1           0
sku2    2           0           1
sku3    2           2           0
```

I can get one *half* of the data using this:

```
SELECT sku, count(*)
    FROM skudata
    WHERE `dest_loc` = "LOC1"
    GROUP BY `sku`, `source_loc`
    ORDER BY `sku`;
```

I need to also add in the WHERE source_loc = "LOC1". I could run the two queries separately, but then I'd have to stitch the results together, which would be a pain. How could I better write the query to include both "directions"?

Comment: why you have outbound 1 for SKU1  youhave dest_loc LOC1 and LOC2  ..  if you want the outbound you should have 2 for this sku ... please check  ..

Comment: As is mentioned above, Your `outbound` value for `sku1` should be 2 based on the logic.

Comment: also I am curious the outbound=0 instead of 2 for sku2.

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the feedback. SKU1 has 3 records. Two of them have a dest_loc of LOC1, so they are inbound. The last has a source loc of LOC1 and some other value for dest_loc, so that one is an outbound. LOC1 is the reference point, so anything with dest_loc of LOC1 is coming in, and with a source_loc of LOC1 is going out, if it's dest_loc is not also LOC1 (in which case the SKU was "sent to it's origin", which still equates to an inbound). The third sku1 is further down in the table, since that's reflective of the data set (unordered by sku).

Comment: This leads me to a follow-on question... if a SKU has LOC1 set for both source and dest location, it may be getting counted twice, so I think a condition needs to be added where src=dest=LOC1?

Comment: Ah, I think I can do: SUM( IF(source_loc = 'LOC1' AND dest_loc != 'LOC1', 1, 0)) AS outbound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for multiple WHERE statements. These can be placed in the SELECT portion as conditionals:

```
SELECT 
  sku,
  SUM(IF(dest_loc   = 'LOC1', 1, 0)) AS inbound,
  SUM(IF(source_loc = 'LOC1', 1, 0)) AS outbound,
  SUM(IF(dest_loc   = 'REC' , 1, 0)) AS recycle
FROM skudata
GROUP BY sku
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your data seems that you are looking for distinct count

```
SELECT sku, 
      count(distinct source_loc) inbound, 
      count(distinct dest_loc) outbound, 
      sum(case when dest_loc ='REC' then 1 else 0 end) recycle
FROM skudata
GROUP BY `sku`
ORDER BY `sku`;
```